# I want to open a popup window on a click and insert a button in the new window to allow closing by user

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a popup window from a home page us an on click button, then in that popup, I want to place an onclick button t close the popup.   I have the pop open working but can't figure out how to do the rest.  Here is my code:

I have the open popup working from a button in the parent window.  I need the close window button in the popup window.

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>

<button id="myBtn">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
    var myWindow;

    function openWin() {
        myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=400, height=200");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
        myWindow.document.getElementByID("myBtn").onclick = closeWin;
     }

     function closeWin() {
         myWindow.close();
     }
</script>
```

Both buttons work but both are in the parent window.  Need the win.close button to be placed in the popup window.

Comment: Well you need to add a button to the new window. I do not see it in your code. And all you need to do is `<button onclick='window.close();'>`

Comment: I know that and have added it several times.  The problem is; how to put that close button in the popup window.  where do i code i?.  everytime I try it appears in the parent window not the popup window.

Comment: The line `myWindow.document.write(....` Add it in there....

Answer (score 0):

```
wnd.document.write("<button id='myBtn'>Close Window</button>");
wnd.document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = 
    function() {
        wnd.close();
        };
    return false;
    };
```